# SQL query that leverages the postgres ILIKE function on multiple values from a table field given a list of IDS

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

I have two tables that are associated, `vehicles` and `models`. The `vehicles` table has a `model_id` field and the `models` table has a `name` field. Given a list of `model` ids, I'd like to return a list of vehicles that are associated with any model that begins with the `name` of the `model` whose id was included in the list. How can I accomplish this?

I've looked into leveraging the ILIKE function in postgres but have been unable to produce a functioning sql query that will pass in the `names` of the `models` provided as an array to ILIKE.

Any insight/direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you share with us a specific query that you're using?  Might be a syntax issue?

Comment: I don't even have a functioning query to show you. I am unsure of how to write the sql to accomplish this goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
SELECT *
  FROM vehicles
 WHERE model_id IN (SELECT id
                      FROM models
                     WHERE name ILIKE ANY (SELECT name||'%'
                                             FROM models
                                            WHERE id IN (<array of model IDs>)
                                          )
                   );
```

Disclosure: I am an [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://enterprisedb.com) employee

Comment: So would it be a subquery to the the model names in `'%<insert model name here>%'`? Can the ILIKE function take an array of names?

Comment: If it's an array you want, then `ILIKE ANY (ARRAY['%foo%', '%bar%', '%baz%']);` should work

Comment: So how can I get the names of the `models` given the ids passed in and format them in the array for the ILIKE? I need to pass int he name from `model` `1` and `2` to the ilike function.

Comment: And would you have a sample list of model names you're working with?  I'm guessing if `models.id = 1` corresponds to `models.name = 'Corolla'`, you want `vehicles` with `model_id` corresponding to any `models.id` where name could be "Corolla," "Corolla Hatchback," etc.?

Comment: That is exactly right!  "Wrangler", "Wrangler Unlimited", "Wrangler JK Unlimited", "Wrangler JK" should work.